# decltype((x)) with double brackets what does it mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue-reference, decltype

Very simple question, I'm unable to google out the answer.

For example:

```
int a = 0;
int& b = x;
int&& c = 1;

decltype((a)) x; // what is the type of x?
decltype((b)) y; // what is the type of y?
decltype((c)) z; // what is the type of z?
```

Maybe I should assign x,y and z to some value to get different results, I'm not sure.

**EDIT:**
According to site below double brackets turn example `int` into a reference:
https://github.com/AnthonyCalandra/modern-cpp-features#decltype

```
int a = 1; // `a` is declared as type `int`
int&& f = 1; // `f` is declared as type `int&&`
decltype(f) g = 1; // `decltype(f) is `int&&`
decltype((a)) h = g; // `decltype((a))` is int&
```

Comment: (a),(b),(c) are l-value expressions. same like decltype(a = 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [C++ Primer](https://books.google.az/books?id=J1HMLyxqJfgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=C%2B%2B%20Primer&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihkeHKouHiAhViwqYKHYH_B14Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=C%2B%2B%20Primer&f=false):

> When we apply `decltype` to a variable without any parentheses, we get
>   the type of that variable. If we wrap the variable’s name in one or
>   more sets of parentheses, the compiler will evaluate the operand as an
>   expression. A variable is an expression that can be the left-hand side
>   of an assignment. As a result, `decltype` on such an expression yields
>   a reference:
>
> ```
> // decltype of a parenthesized variable is always a reference
> decltype((i)) d; // error: d is int& and must be initialized
> decltype(i) e;   // ok: e is an (uninitialized) int
> ```

Answer (score 7):

All of them are of type `int&`.

Adding parentheses like `(a)` makes them *expressions* (instead of *entity*), which are all lvalues (as named variables); then [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) yields to `T&`, i.e. `int&` here.

> ...
>
> 4) If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
>
> ...
>
> b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields
>   `T&`;
>
> ...

You can check the actual types with this [LIVE DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tInLyNR91pqny0Un) (from the compiling error messages).

Answer (score 4):

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as
>   an ordinary lvalue expression, thus decltype(x) and decltype((x)) are
>   often different types.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

As far as I understand, `(x)` is an empty expression which returns a reference to `x`. Thus

- `decltype(x)` is `int`
- `declytpe((x))` is `int&`